# Caching WebSockets

Tags: caching, ssl, websocket, varnish, haproxy

One question I have in mind is it possible to cache web-sockets from the first place?
In my topology I have 2 Apache server(with Google PageSpeed Module) behind a HAProxy server that is connected to the internet via dual ISP connection. My users are using the side xxx.com with dynamic and static web content which at the moment is not being cached (since varnish doesn’t support SSL/TLS)

My plan is to put varnish in the same machine where HAProxy is running, and use it (the varnish server) as a backed of the HAProxy.

So at the end I will have something like this:

HAProxy(With SSL) + Varnish -> Apache 1 or Apache 2 as webserver backend
HAProxy(With SSL) -> Jetty 1 or Jetty 2 as websockets backend

Jetty is connected to the Jboss application server with Mongo+MqSL+Neo4j as the DB backend.

This will give me nice way to cache dynamic and static connect using varnish, keep SSL using HAProxy and keep my topology clean.

But, there is anther key server in my solution:
I’m using Jetty (with cometd) for web-sockets implementation (I was thinking to move to Socket.io, or SockJS with Web-Stomp), that is being route via the HAProxy.

I used Clustered Cometd via OORT and I want to understand if there is any point in caching this contents as it consider to be Real Time Data.
The reason I’m asking is that I’m thinking to move to some CDN solution to speed up my performance, but as far as I see it – Websockets can’t be cached so the all point here is just pushing more static and dynamic content.

Is that make sense or I’m losing here something?

Thanks
Sassy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tunnel websockets through a caching proxy (not all support this), but caching websockets itself will not work, because they don't fit in the necessary scheme for caching, e.g. one requests which results in the same response every time.